# VIM: Regex \zs \ze problem

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to delete all text in lines from the 2nd character till the last `.word\` pattern (deleting also the dot), but there may not be a `\` before the dot. If there is a `\` before the dot then delete till the previous `.word\` pattern.

I created this simple regex:
`^\w\zs.*[^\]\.\ze\w\+\\\s.*$`
but this doesn't work

What did I wrong?

What would be the code if I don't want to delete till the last `.word\` but till the 2nd `.word\` pattern?

data:
`nnoremenu <silent> 97.330.10 &Sort.Reverse\ Characters.Reverse\ Characters\ in\ Line\ Hor\ -[A]<Tab>sihT\ si\ ym\ txet\.\

nnoremenu <silent> 97.330.11 &Sort.Reverse\ Characters.Reverse\ Characters\ in\ Line\ Hor\ Reverse\ -[A]<Tab>\.txet\ ym\ si\ sihT\`

must be:
`n Reverse\ Characters\ in\ Line\ Hor\ -[A]<Tab>sihT\ si\ ym\ txet\.\

 n Reverse\ Characters\ in\ Line\ Hor\ Reverse\ -[A]<Tab>\.txet\ ym\ si\ sihT\`

Comment: Some example data might be helpful.

Comment: Some data is obligatory. You can't expect us to read a (proven) wrong regular expression and guess what you meant with that incomplete description

Comment: @johnny, @sehe, please see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
:%s/^\w\zs.*\\\@<!\.\ze\w\+\\\s
```

Note that the final `\s` means that you require a space after the last backslash.

The `\@<!` helper means: lookbehind negative assertion (see `:help /\@<!`).

Also note that the final `.*$` is useless.

Comment: thank you. That resolved my 1st question. Our regex does select always the latest pattern `w\+\\\s`, what would be the code to select the 2nd pattern?  p.e. If I do a search to find 2 or more spaces in a text p.e. `^[a|v|n].*\(\s\{2,}\)\{1}`, it find the last 2 or more spaces in a line. How can I search the first 2 or more spaces in a line?

Comment: Use : `\(^.\{-} \{2,}\@=\)\@>\zs`. See `:help /\@>` for those things.

Comment: thanks Benoit, that resolved my question. Btw why doesn't this working: `^[a|v|n].*\(\s\{2,}\)\{1}` isn't that the same as your code? Your code works, my code doesn't :)